# Using Breeze.js with Dapper

Tags: web-applications, breeze, dapper, single-page-application

I am considering using Breeze.js for a client-side SPA project, but using Dapper ORM instead of Entity Framework for the server-side data access.

I know Breeze.js is marketed as not relying on EF, but it's clearly targeted towards it.

Has anyone tried using Dapper ORM or some other framework on the server to replace EF in conjunction with Breeze?

Are there any particular concerns or "gotchas" that I should be aware of going into this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will have examples and server side code showing how to integrate Breeze with both NHibernate and MongoDb within the next few weeks.  This should provide better examples of how to integrate any other backends, such as Dapper, with Breeze.

Per Dapper specifically, please add a request to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  We take these suggestions and the associated vote counts very seriously in determining what to work on next.

Comment: I deleted my ill-informed answer; thank you for correcting me. If you need any assistance etc for dapper support, let me know.

Comment: Marc, I saw your original answer, and it made sense to me, even if wrong :).  Can you relay the correction here so I understand better?

Comment: Joseph - If you'd like to accelerate integration with Dapper, shoot us an email at breeze@ideablade.com. We should be able help you with this.

Comment: @Joseph my misunderstanding was that I *believed* (from reading some intro pages, etc) that breeze.js was tied pretty tightly to OData and similar. If occurs, though, that dapper is still pretty far away from what breeze.js wants to do. I wonder whether Simple.Data is a better match, actually.